# Can the TFT in LCD displays be made in the nanometer range?

Tags: lcd, manufacturing-process

Can the TFT elements and hence the pixels in an LCD display be made in the nanometer range? Say 10nm x 10nm?

Comment: What is the use of 10 nm pixels for light with a wavelength between 400 and 800 nm?

Comment: why are you asking? .... what are your thoughts about this?

Comment: The 10nm x 10nm is approximate size of the TFT elements but not for the sole purpose of transmitting light. In fact the elements might as large as 100nm x 100nm. I'm just throwing out small values to indicate the TFT will be small. I'm more concerned with having a low size (high resolution) of LCD elements to manipulate. And if, and it's a BIG "if", many 10nm x 10nm elements in concert are working together they could be used form structures with the LCDs other than those used for the standard (large) RGB pixels.

Answer (score 1):

TFTs features are made by repetitions of a coat,photoresist,etch process 
using ordinary ultraviolet light same as PCB manufacture.

Even X-ray photo-lithography is challenging at 10nm (Intel makes chips with 14nm features. that's feature size, actual transistors will be several times larger.